# how to show sum of labor hours by workorder in maximo start center resultset

Tags: sql, resultset, maximo

I have to create a Result set graph in Maximo Start Center that shows workorders and sum of their all associated  actual labor hours from LABTRANS. for example, if wonum '1001' in workorder table with three labors in labtrans table having regularhrs 3,2 and 4 then I have to create a resultset(or resultset graph) that show this workorder '1001' and its labor hours sum 3+2+4=9. Currently after adding relationship to WOTRACK by adding ATTRIBUTE 'LABTRANS.REGULARHRS' with APP 'WOTRACK' and MAINTABLE 'WORKORDER' in RESULTSETCOLS table I am getting workorder and its first labor hours(not all..in above case wonum='1001' and regularhrs 3). Please help me to resolve this issue...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In workorder table there is a field called actlabhrs which sums up the labor hours. Rather than create a relationship to labtrans table, you just use the workorder table. Labtrans can have multiple labor entries so it is not ideal for a result set. If you use workorder as your main object, the actlabhrs already sums up your hours for you as part of the labor entry and approval process.

Comment: Thank you very much..I tried it and working properly...but my next question is  I have to create a Result set graph in Maximo Start Center that shows  sum of actual labor hours instead of showing count(*) on Y axis. for example, if siteid 'ABC'  has three workorders '1001','1002' and '1003' in workorder table with 3,2 and 4 actual labor hours respectively then I have to create a resultset(or resultset graph) that show this site 'ABC' and its labor hours sum 3+2+4=9, instead of showing count 3 on Y axis. Please help me to resolve this issue...thanks in advance